# How to retrieve the muliple checkbox value in form

Tags: magento-1.7, database, forms, checkbox

I tried to display the values from database but failed to display.,

First I inserted the values using checkbox.,

codes are below,

```
$fieldset->addField('city', 'checkboxes', array(
                'label' => $this->__('City'),
                'name' => 'city[]',
                'required' => true,
                "checked" => $city,
                'values' => array(
                    array('value' => '0', 'label' => 'aaaaa'),
                    array('value' => '1', 'label' => 'bbbbbbb'),
                    array('value' => '2', 'label' => 'ccccccc'),
                    array('value' => '3', 'label' => 'dddddddd'),
                    array('value' => '4', 'label' => 'eeeeeeee')
                ),
                'onclick' => "",
                'onchange' => "",
                'disabled' => false,
                'value'  => '1',
                'tabindex' => 1
            ));
```

after that,

```
$city = $post_data['city'] = implode(',', $post_data['city']);
```

using above code inserted successfully like(0,1,2),

```
 if ($object->getData('city')) {
                $city = $object->getData('city');
                $city = explode(",", $city);
                 //var_dump($city);die;
            }
```

inserted value I get successfully, Now I want to display the checked one(0,1,2)

Any one please help to solve this!!!!!!

Comment: $city = explode(",", $city); what you get here, in array format like array(0=>0,1=>1,2=>2) right?

Comment: @saravanavelu yes

Comment: while edit the form with particular record need to show only selected value right?

Comment: @saravanavelu yes

Comment: check my answer it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the code as below,

```
   $fieldset->addField('city', 'checkboxes', array(
                    'label' => $this->__('City'),
                    'name' => 'city[]',
                    'required' => true,
                    "checked" => $city,
                    'values' => $this->getOptionValues($city),
                    'onclick' => "",
                    'onchange' => "",
                    'disabled' => false,
                    'value'  => '1',
                    'tabindex' => 1
                ));
```

Create a new function to get the option values,

```
 public function getOptionValues($city)

     $result = array();

     $selectedvalues =  $city; //exploded array

     $optionslists = array(
                            array('value' => '0', 'label' => 'aaaaa'),
                            array('value' => '1', 'label' => 'bbbbbbb'),
                            array('value' => '2', 'label' => 'ccccccc'),
                            array('value' => '3', 'label' => 'dddddddd'),
                            array('value' => '4', 'label' => 'eeeeeeee')
                        );

    if(count($selectedvalues)>1){
        foreach($selectedvalues as $selectedvalue ){
                foreach($optionslists as $optionslist)
                {
                    if(in_array($selectedvalue, $optionslist))
                    {
                        $result[] = $optionslist;
                    }

                }
            }
    }
    else{
       $result = $optionslists; 
    }
    return $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$city = $post_data['city'];
foreach($city as $k => $c){
   if(isset($city[$k])){
      echo $c;
   }
}
```

I haven't tested, but should give you the checked one.